# Adding subclass to list - The method add(capture#2-of ? extends TopBean)...not applicable for the arguments (TopBean)

Tags: java, inheritance

I've asked this question before but never got a solution what to do.

I am trying to add a subtype to a list defined as follows. This should be 100% legal, the subtype extends the main type.

```
private List<? extends TopBean> beans;

public List<? extends TopBean> getBeans() {
        return beans;
}
```

I am trying to do this:

```
this.getBeans().add(new SecondaryBean());
```

**SecondaryBean extends TopBean** (not directly but at some level).

This is driving me nuts - the error is

```
The method add(capture#2-of ? extends TopBean) in the type List<capture#2-of ? extends TopBean> is not applicable for the arguments (SecondaryBean)
```

If I cast it to TopBean, same error, just diffent wording

T`he method add(capture#2-of ? extends TopBean) in the type List<capture#2-of ? extends TopBean> is not applicable for the arguments (TopBean)`

I **must** add a child SecondaryBean into the List of generic TopBeans. What to do here?

Answer (score 3):

you can't add any non-null to wild cards defined this way.

if you would have defined it

```
List<? super TopBean>
```

then adding anything extending TopBean was possible but getting was a different story - only things that TopBean extends or implements

I don't understand why you define your list as a wildcard at the first place, defining it as List seems to give you everything you need. methods sometimes should be defined with wikdcards but not the data members

Answer (score 0):

Basically your declaration is wrong.  Don't use wild cards in a variable declaration or a return type.  Only use wildcards for method parameters.

```
private List<TopBean> beans;

public List<TopBean> getBeans() {
        return beans;
}
```

There could be a lot of reasons and discussion why you don't use wild cards anywhere but method parameters, but that's my personal general rule.  It's overly simplistic but will cover 90% - 99% of all real world use of generics in Java.

Now with the above code I've given, you can add a TopBean to your list, or any subclass of TopBean.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. With the below cast, the error went away (there's a warning but I can live with that).

```
((List<SecondaryBean>)this.getBeans()).add(new SecondaryBean());
```

I am guaranteed to have a List of SecondaryBeans, so this is safe.